# Reference a column in another sheet using column name (heading) in Google Sheets inside an ArrayFormula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, syntax, match

I have an example sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i96cjWWGwLQQd2enqQhLylFo31n5GyxbCTcTEPk2I2A/edit#gid=0.

I have two parts to my question.

## Part 1

In the `names` sheet, in `C1`, I have this formula:

```
={
    "Is Special";
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(
            A2:A <> "",
            REGEXMATCH(B2:B, "b|d|e"),
        )
    )
}
```

The formula works as expected but I do not like the `B2:B` reference because it is not easily obvious what column I am checking against. I'd rather refer to the column by it's name (`First Name` in this case). Is that possible? Can I replace `B2:B` with some formula or function that lets me lookup the column range by searching for `First Name`? I know I can use `MATCH` to get the column number for `First Name` but I'm not sure how to put that into this formula -- especially since I cannot use `INDRECT` in an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Something like:

```
={
    "Is Special";
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(
            A2:A <> "",
            REGEXMATCH([some formula or function that lets me lookup the column range by searching for "First Name"], "b|d|e"),
        )
    )
}
```

## Part 2

Similar to above, on the `names` sheet, in `D1` I have this formula:

```
={
    "Count of one Properties";
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(
            A2:A <> "",
            COUNTIFS(
                properties!A:A, A2:A,
                properties!B:B, "one"
            ),
        )
    )
}
```

The formula works as expected. However, I do not like the `properties!B:B` reference. Reading the formula it is not obvious what column from the `properties` sheet I am checking against. Is it possible to something similar like above where I get the column range by searching for the column name, in this case `type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you dont like named ranges try:

```
={"Is Special"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 REGEXMATCH(FILTER({A2:B, D2:E}, {A1:B1, D1:E1}="First Name"), "b|d|e"), ))}
```

[image]

or like:

```
={"Count of one Properties"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 COUNTIFS(properties!A2:A, A2:A, 
 VLOOKUP(ROW(properties!A2:A),{ROW(properties!A2:A), properties!A2:Z}, 
 MATCH("type", properties!1:1, 0)+1, 0), "one"), ))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you are familiar with "named ranges":

[image]

[image]

```
={"Is Special"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", REGEXMATCH(FirstName, "b|d|e"), ))}
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
={"Is Special"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 REGEXMATCH(QUERY(FirstName, "offset 1", 0), "b|d|e"), ))}
```

[image]

Comment: Named ranges don't auto update. If I try to create a named range on `A2:A` it'll create on `A2:A1000`. Then if I add more rows, the named range won't update. I can create a named range on `A:A` but that doesn't work nicely with `ARRAYFORMULA` since the array formula needs to start on row 2.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan you can still do it. answer updated...

Comment: I see. This is interesting. Thanks. But I'll mark the first one as answer since that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!